# "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed." i have not set it as GET so why is it showing this error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

i am trying yo create a new item but i am getting `"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed` error on page of django rest framework and `405 (Method Not Allowed)` error in console. Any help will be appericiated (writing this cuz i need to add more words to post it please dont mind it)

views.py:

```
def create_person(request):
    serializer = PersonSerializer(data=request.data, many=False)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def all_persons(request):
    person = Person.objects.all()
    serializer = PersonSerializer(person, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def person(request, pk):
    person = Person.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = PersonSerializer(person, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
def create_person(request):
    serializer = PersonSerializer(data=request.data, many=False)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
    
@api_view(['PUT'])
def update_person(request, pk):
    person = Person.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = PersonSerializer(data=request.data, instance=person, many=False)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
    
@api_view(['DELETE'])
def delete_person(request, pk):
    person = Person.objects.get(id=pk)
    person.delete()
    return Response('item with id deleted')
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.apiOverview, name='apiOverview'),
    path('persons/', views.all_persons, name='all_persons'),
    path('person/<str:pk>', views.person, name='person'),
    path('person-create/', views.create_person, name='create'),
    path('person-update/<str:pk>', views.update_person, name='update_person'),
    path('person-delete/<str:pk>', views.delete_person, name='delete_person'),
]
```

fixed urls and views in edits

Comment: Which URL are you requesting and where is the rest of your views? Your urls don't reference `create_person` anywhere

Comment: a.s. because you access the endpoint via the browser which equals an automatic `GET`.

Comment: @IainShelvington sorry i had to text editors open i fixed the urls  also create_person is the view which has problem. hope u can help now

Comment: The `create-person` function *is* the view... function based

Comment: Can you post the full traceback from the error?

Comment: `create_person` only accepts POST requests as per the `api_view` decorator

Comment: this is the error in terminal (Bad Request: /api/person-create/
[29/Nov/2021 14:08:13] "POST /api/person-create/ HTTP/1.1" 400 5775)

Comment: yes because when i create a person i am creating a new one

Comment: also in api it dosent give me a button to choose an image